# Community Builder Napili Template: Profile Header Missing (can't logout)

Tags: community-builder, napili

In a pre-configured community (someone else set this up), I do not see the Profile Header - the widget that lets you log out.  Item 2 in the below image.
[image: Annotated Napili Header screenshot]

In the Page Editor, I don't see it and can't click on, but if I switch to the Page Structure outline view, I see it under Template Header where it belongs, and if I click on it, I see an empty outline in the Template Header preview where it should be; I can also see its properties in the Property Editor inspector on the right.  I've compared these settings to another Napili community where the Profile Header is present, and I can find no differences.  I've checked every community setting I can think of.  I've also confirmed that I'm using the latest version of Napili Summer '16.

Also possibly relevant - the search box is also present in the Page Structure outline, but not visible.  I don't want it be visible, but I don't know how/why it is hidden or if it's related.

How can I make the Property Header visible again?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you enabled the **Hide the header region and navigation** option do and disable that option

Builder -> settings -> Themes -> Edit Home and Disable **Hide the header region and navigation**